# Using Function within VBA Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a function within my Sub but am getting a compile error on the line `x = NINOFunction()` and am not sure how to get it working.

```
Sub CheckNINO()
    Dim NINumber As Range, NINumbers As Range
    Dim Usdrws As Long, x As Boolean

    Usdrws = Worksheets("EeeDetails").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set NINumbers = Worksheets("EeeDetails").Range("Q2:Q" & Usdrws)

    For Each NINumber In NINumbers
        x = NINOFunction(NINumber.Value)
        If x = False Then
            Range(NINumber).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Validation").Cells(2, x)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function NINOFunction(sInp As String) As Boolean
    Const s1 As String = "[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnOoPpRrSsTtWwXxYyZz]"
    Const s2 As String = "[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtWwXxYyZz]"
    Const s3 As String = "######"
    Const s4 As String = "[AaBbCcDd]"

    NINO = sInp Like s1 & s2 & s3 & s4
End Function
```

The function is tested and works with a Boolean result.

If the result is False I want to copy the row across to a separate sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compilation error is "Argument is not optional". This is quite good error message. Thus write `x = NINOFunction(arg)` and put an argument `sInp`.

Something like `x = NINOFunction ("something")`

or probably you need:

`x = NINOFunction (NINumber)`

Furthermore, your function always returns `False`, because this is the default value of the Boolean function. You may consider fixing it like this:

```
Function NINOFunction(sInp As String) As Boolean
    Const s1 As String = "[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnOoPpRrSsTtWwXxYyZz]"
    Const s2 As String = "[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtWwXxYyZz]"
    Const s3 As String = "######"
    Const s4 As String = "[AaBbCcDd]"

    NINOFunction = sInp Like s1 & s2 & s3 & s4
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Vityata, thanks for the response, I'm still getting a `compile error: Argument not optional` error though

Comment: I was wondering about your original response. The parameter to the NINOFunction function is not optional. [edit] Your last reponse looks like a call to a procedure; not a function.

Comment: @Jeeped - yup true. I have simply started to remove parenthesis everywhere in `Subs` since the last week, thus this new habit results in flaws like the one above.

Comment: Excellent thanks Vityata, I was wondering why they were all returning False, didn't realise I hadn't updated the Variable name at the end!!

Answer (score 0):

`NINOFunction` takes 1 argument, which is a string, but you didn't pass any. Try `x = NINOFunction("something")`

Comment: And, of course, replace "something" with the desired input string.

Comment: Thanks Magnetron, I was unaware that I had to assign the function like that, but it makes perfect sense!